# Ranked data and hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, dataset, ranking

I have a few questions regarding ranked data and hypothesis testing.
Hypothesis: Car drivers are more likely to consider the car as the most beneficial transportation method for mental health than other transport method users'.
Respondents were asked to rank 4 transport methods from least (1) to most (4) beneficial to mental health.
Responses were as follows
[image]

A Fisher’s Exact Test test gives me a p=0.001 for the variables in the picture above. The Fisher's test shows that there is a significant relationship between the variables, however, that would prove a hypothesis such as: 'Mode of transport influences the perception on which transport provides the most mental health benefits.' However, I want to know if car drivers are more likely to think this way.  What test should I do here?
Thank you for your help.

Kind regards,

P.S. New image with more detail added as a response to comment below.

[image]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to CV! Could you provide the contingency table used for the test?

Comment: Not your hypothesis but, can you show some plots of all the 4 rankings? For a visual comparison.

Comment: @utobi I updated the post with a picture of it. Can you see it? I am not sure if it shows for everyone. Thank you!

Comment: @user2974951 yes, I have done that. Thanks!

Comment: "A Fisher’s Exact Test test gives me a p=0.0478. But that doesn't prove my hypothesis." Generally, if you run one test and then try another because the first one doesn't give you the result you want, the second test is no longer valid because its theory assumes that it is not picked conditionally on results from the data. You can't just test until you find a result you like. Apart from this, I'm not sure what kind of "proof" you expect, and what's wrong with Fisher's p. (I assume this was computed based on the full table with all four ranks?)

Comment: @ChristianHennig The fisher's test proves that there is a significant relationship between the variables, however, that would prove a hypothesis such as: 'Mode of transport influences the perception on which transport provides the most mental health benefits.' However, I want to know if car drivers are more likely to think this way. So, the fisher's test was only done as an extra test, not to try tests until I receive the result I want, that would be unethical. However, I don't know which test I have to perform at all in the case I am looking at. Could you help me, please?

Comment: The table you provided is not what I had in mind, can you expand the table and in the rows include all 4 methods of transportation (first rank)? That way we can see each transportation frequency. Are you sure that this grouping will answer your hypothesis? What if for ex. all those other 35 drivers ranked trains first, would you still say that drivers ranked cars higher than non-drivers?

Comment: @user2974951 you are so right! I didn't even think of that. Thanks for saying, however, now I am even more confused on what to do. I added a new picture in the post as I can't seem to attach it to the comment. Thank you so much for helping me, you are great!

Comment: Thanks for the second image, it helps. There are some options available, based on the second table you could say that the proportion of people **that rank cars as rank 1** is indeed higher in drivers than in non-drivers (you could use a proportion test for this). However there are other options that are not specific just to rank 1 answers, maybe the results would be different if you were to look at answers for rank 2 etc., so you need to think about your hypothesis and define exactly what you are interested in, maybe you are interested in an average rank.